# How to remove small squares at the bottom of a chart, in swift4 chart library

Tags: ios, charts, swift4

I want try remove small squares at the bottom of a chart( danielgindi/Charts).

post picture.

plz help me....

[chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1rkE.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple 
juste a line

`chartView.legend.isEnabled = false`

Comment: Thanks!!!! thank you for save my time!! 
I solve this problem using below line.

Comment: hartView.legend.enabled = false